# Unity: How to detect middle mouse release in Editor Window?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

How to detect middle mouse release in Editor Window?
Code below is not working:

```
Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp
```

Comment: How is the code not working? Is it also catching the other mouse buttons? If that is the case, you can use (Event.current.button == 2) to verify that it is in fact the middle button. See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-button.html

Comment: i need release middle button event, not click. MouseUp event catch only left and right mouse buttons. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Could you show us where you are checking this please?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a fool myself :-D. I tried again and it's working